# MS Visual 2013 with GDAL and HDF 4

Tags: gdal, visual-studio, hdf

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013, C++ and newest gdal downloaded from here http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1800-x64-dev.zip
In readme and libraries I can see HDF 4 and 5, but when I'm doing `GDALAllRegister();` and calling

```
GDALGetDriverShortName(hDriver),
GDALGetDriverLongName(hDriver));
```

to check drivers, I'm getting only this list of drivers:
[image]

As you can see, there is no HDF. How to turn it on or register?

Comment: Does your path environment variable have a reference to your GDAL install location? I have experimented with my install and removing/changing other GDAL system variables aren't as important as having c:\program files\gdal early in your %PATH%, about 6 or 7th entry worked for me.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson we set it with you in my last question. GDAL dll and libs are updated, so it should work..